# How to return the ID of the Inserted Record to C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this stored procedure:

```
Insert into dbo.file_row (file_sub_type) values (@file_sub_type)
DECLARE @result int;
SET @result = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
RETURN @result;
```

This works fine to return the id in SSMS.  However, when I call it from C#, it returns -1.

```
var connection = GetSqlConnection();
connection.Open();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = "InsertInto_file_row";
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@file_sub_type", fileType));

int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
return result;
```

I don't see what I am doing wrong. I just need the Id of the inserted record.

Greg

Comment: use `ExecuteScalar` - `ExecuteNonQuery` will return rows affected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the docs on [ExecuteNonQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx):

> Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and **returns the number of rows affected.**

*(Emphasis mine)*

If you want to get information back, you have a couple options:

1. Change `RETURN` to `SELECT` and `ExecuteNonQuery()` to `ExecuteScalar()`
2. Use an [`OUTPUT` parameter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: 8 Years later, I mark this as the answer. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Joel's response
Try ExecuteScalar instead

Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored. (Overrides DbCommand.ExecuteScalar().)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you. The function returns the new Identity column value if a new row was inserted, 0 on failure. It is from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

```
static public int AddProductCategory(string newName, string connString)
{
   Int32 newProdID = 0;
   string sql =
    "INSERT INTO Production.ProductCategory (Name) VALUES (@Name); "
    + "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
  {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = newName;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        newProdID = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
return (int)newProdID;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public int AddProductCategory(string newName, string connString)
    {
          string sql =
    "INSERT INTO Production.ProductCategory (Name) VALUES (@Name); "
    + "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", newName);
               
                con.Open();
                latestInsertedId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                con.Close();
            }
            return latestInsertedId ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).